# Translation API with candidates

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, translation, google-translate

I am looking for a translation API that outputs all the candidates and not just single "best" candidate.

All statistical machine translation systems at the last stage score the list of translation candidates and choice the best candidate. I wonder if there is a system like Google translate or Microsoft translate that returns the list of all possible candidates so that I will be able to score them by myself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think WordNet is good for this:
https://wordnet.princeton.edu/

Originally wordnet is english ontology describing english word in english, showing synonims, definition etc. but there are a lot of other language wordnets projects as well as multilingual wordnets. Below interesting links:
http://globalwordnet.org/wordnets-in-the-world/
http://www.certifiedchinesetranslation.com/openaccess/WordNet/

There is a big dictionary project leveraging from wordnets too:
http://babelnet.org/about